# how to count repeated sentence in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

```
cat file1.txt
abc bcd abc ...
abcd bcde cdef ...
abcd bcde cdef ...
abcd bcde cdef ...
efg fgh ...
efg fgh ...
hig ...
```

My expected result is like as below:

```
abc bcd abc ...      

abcd bcde cdef ...  
<!!! pay attention, above sentence has repeated 3 times !!!>

efg fgh ...
<!!! pay attention, above sentence has repeated 3 times !!!>

hig ...
```

I have found a way to deal with the issues, but my code is a little noisy.

```
cat file1.txt | uniq -c | sed -e 's/ \+/ /g' -e 's/^.//g' | awk '{print $0," ",$1}'| sed -e 's/^[2-9] /\n/g' -e 's/^[1] //g' |sed -e 's/[^1]$/\n<!!! pay attention, above sentence has repeated & times !!!> \n/g' -e 's/[1]$//g'

abc bcd abc ...

abcd bcde cdef ...
<!!! pay attention, above sentence has repeated 3 times !!!>

efg fgh ...
<!!! pay attention, above sentence has repeated 2 times !!!>

hig ...
```

I was wondering if you could show me more high-efficiency way to achieve the goal.Thanks a lot.

Comment: If `abcd bcde cdef ...` appeared 2 more times at the end of your input file, should the output say that the line repeated 5 times or that it repeated 3 times and then repeated 2 times?

Comment: Probably my formulation is not very clear, I have used the "sort" function to rank the rows at first, thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're lines are not already grouped, then you could use

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {count[$0]++; next} 
    !seen[$0]++ {
        print
        if (count[$0] > 1)
            print "... repeated", count[$0], "times"
    }
' file1.txt file1.txt
```

This will consume a lot of memory if your file is very large. You might want to sort it first.

Comment: OK, thanks, I have sort the rows before, in my current question,I didn't explain it clearly, I will polish my formulation next time.

Answer (score 2):

**`sort`** + **`uniq`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
sort file1.txt | uniq -c | sed -E 's/^ +1 (.+)/\1\n/; 
 s/^ +([2-9]|[0-9]{2,}) (.+)/\2\n<!!! pay attention, the above sentence has repeated \1 times !!!>\n/'
```

The output:

```
abc bcd abc ...

abcd bcde cdef ...
<!!! pay attention, the above sentence has repeated 3 times !!!>

efg fgh ...
<!!! pay attention, the above sentence has repeated 2 times !!!>

hig ...
```

---

Or with **`awk`**:

```
sort file1.txt | uniq -c | awk '{ n=$1; sub(/^ +[0-9]+ +/,""); 
printf "%s\n%s",$0,(n==1? ORS:"<!!! pay attention, the above sentence has repeated "n" times !!!>\n\n") }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
    $0==prev { cnt++; next }
    { prt(); prev=$0; cnt=1 }
    END { prt() }
    function prt() {
        if (NR>1) print prev (cnt>1 ? ORS "repeated " cnt " times" : "") ORS
    }
' file
abc bcd abc ...

abcd bcde cdef ...
repeated 3 times

efg fgh ...
repeated 2 times

hig ...
```

Comment: I think you're only supposed to print the record if `cnt == 1`